# Able to run Android application from Eclipse, but not directly from phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an application that I can debug/run from Eclipse, but if I try and run the application on its own from the phone, it just goes straight to my home screen.  Others are able to run the application in this manner, so it makes me doubt that it is an issue with the application.

I am able to run other applications I have written from the phone as well, but I'm not sure where I should be looking to fix this.

Comment: first thing to try is uninstall and re-install it on your device.

Comment: Urrrm, look at logcat when try to start it on your phone and see what's causing the problem might be an idea.

Comment: Only error is the mysterious 'Couldn't get connection factory client' from a map activity

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times as well, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the API level of your phone is equal or higher than the minimum API required for the app. You can check the app API in the minSdkVersion attribute, in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: The minimum API was not defined, but I have added to the manifest, but still no luck.